# PWA login third part on iOS standalone app

Tags: android, iphone, asp.net-mvc, progressive-web-apps, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm working with the pwa, I installed the service worker correctly and I have the manifest file in the root of my project (I work in ASP .NET MVC).
I have also implemented the login from third parties, through facebook, and on android devices when I add the site to my home screen, the standalone app, I start it and log in everything works. But on iOS devices with safari when I try to log in, the device exits the standalone app and takes me to the safari browser so I can log in to the browser but the standalone app does not run. Is it by chance forgetting something? in the poster file do I have to put any particular attribute?
Thank you

Comment: Can you add any details like code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.